# Could not find a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please check your desired capabilities

Tags: ios, appium

I've searched a lot about this error. I've done a lot of tutorials and nothing works:

I've created a test iOS project and it seems that I have everything installed to start working with appium in iOS

```
bacelar@Brunos-MacBook-Pro-2 Test % appium-doctor --ios                
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.15.1
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 12.13.1
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Carthage was found at: /usr/local/bin/carthage. Installed version is: 0.34.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/bacelar
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies completed, no fix needed. ###
```

But when I start inspector session on appium desktop I get the following error:

```
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please check your desired capabilities.
```

Here is the appium log:

```
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/bacelar/Curatio/automatedTests/iOS/test_project/Test/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Test.app","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"iphone 11","noReset":true,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"13.4","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true}}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"app":"/Users/bacelar/Curatio/automatedTests/iOS/test_project/Test/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Test.app","automationName":"XCUITest","deviceName":"iphone 11","noReset":true,"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"13.4","newCommandTimeout":0,"connectHardwareKeyboard":true},null,null]
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1588813098829 (17:58:18 GMT-0700 (PDT))
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1588813098836 (17:58:18 GMT-0700 (PDT))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'XCUITest' and platformName 'iOS'. Please check your desired capabilities.
[MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:226:11)
[MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps [as createSession] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:300:66)
[MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/basedriver/driver.js:376:19)
[MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:482:26)
[MJSONWP]     at executeCommand (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:306:34)
[MJSONWP]     at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:432:15)
[MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[MJSONWP]     at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[MJSONWP]     at Route.dispatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[MJSONWP]     at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[MJSONWP]     at Function.process_params (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[MJSONWP]     at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[MJSONWP]     at logger (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
[MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[MJSONWP]     at trim_prefix (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
[MJSONWP]     at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
[MJSONWP]     at Function.process_params (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[MJSONWP]     at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[MJSONWP]     at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
[MJSONWP]     at invokeCallback (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
[MJSONWP]     at done (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
[MJSONWP]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
[MJSONWP]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
[MJSONWP]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1090:12)
[MJSONWP]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 11 ms - 254
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 1 ms - 57
[HTTP]
```

What should be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours searching I found a way to solve it.

The desires capabilities needs to be:

```
  "xcodeOrgId": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer",
  "udid": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "DEVICE NAME",
  "bundleId": "BUNDLE ID",
  "automationName": "XCUITest"
```

Executing the steps from this tutorial:
https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md

I was getting errors and after executing this command on terminal

```
security unlock-keychain -p ****
```

Everything is working, I can inspect my app and run my automated tests.

Hope it helps if you are getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the values that you pass in your desired capabilities for `deviceName`, `platformName`, `platformVersion` should match to a simulator that is there in your Xcode so that appium can find and start it.

The below set of capabilities has worked for me in the past:

```
File demoAppPath = new File("Demo App");
File demoApp = new File(demoAppPath, "Demo.app");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, demoApp.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 8");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "13.2");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
```

Note that i had a simulator in my Xcode with the name `iPhone 8` and has the iOS version `13.2`. Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and looked at many solutions, but none that worked. Finally, I updated Appium desktop to v1.18.3 and Appium CLI to v1.19.1. It really works. So, it may be version bug.

Comment: BTW, compile WDA and test WDA to your testing device after downloading the new Appium.